# What is the quickest and easiest way to run a non default XAML window in project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I've added a project to my VS10 main project solution.

This new project contains a test window, but I can't run it mauely because the main project has a different xaml window by default.

Is there a simple way to run a specific XAML window, without making it a unit test or changing the project properties ?

I know that it might not be the right way to do it, but I want a fast solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest and easiest way is change `StartupUri` in `App.xaml`.

```
<Application x:Class="WPFDefaultWindow.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="Test.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```